# In MonoDevelop, how do I specify the target directory to be used when generating a package?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, monodevelop, pkg-config

If I right click on the "Tarball" project, and go to Options > Files, I see some like this:

[image]

There are a couple of problems here:

- "pkg-config folder" uses `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, instead of `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`. MonoDevelop itself doesn't look in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` for `.pc` files.
- This is a library, so I don't think I want it installed in "Program Files" (which uses `/usr/local/lib/projectname`. I think it should go in the GAC instead.

In this dialog, the fields are not editable. How can I change the target directory for these files?

I am running MonoDevelop 2.2 on Ubuntu Lucid.